# Example of strongly continuous unitary semigroup where Trotter limit does not exist

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I am looking for an example of two strongly continuous unitary semigroups $U(t),V(t)$ for which the Trotter limit $[U(t/n)V(t/n)]^n \phi$ does not exist for some $t,\phi$.